# UML arrowhead confusion

Tags: uml, class-diagram

The answer to this question is A however I can't wrap my head around how there is a inheritance given the only information is the quote below (ie. a player is not a kind of team). It would make more sense to me not assume a inheritance, and just go with B where there is a simple association. Possibly the answer key is wrong? Also this is not the actual question, i modified it such that it wouldn't break any rules.

> How would you model this situation with a class diagram? Each
> team has many players, and each player can play only in one
> team.

[image]

Comment: The arrow isn't an inheritance arrow, but a unidirectional association. Inheritance arrows have outlined tips and a different shape (triangular, not pointy). You can see both types in this diagram for comparison: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/UML-class-diagram-showing-inheritance-and-association_fig1_327544987

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the question explicitly allude to a unidirectional association if thats the case? (ie. team class has a method that calls on player, and not vice versa?)

Comment: I don't see any methods in the two diagrams, at all. Since you said this is not the actual question, I'M getting the feeling that something is "lost in translation" while you tried to re-create the question here.

Comment: Thats the thing, there isn't any methods listed. The only words I changed in the question are the class names (team and player). Everything thing else is the same.

Comment: Well, you introduced methods in your previous comment, so I was wondering how you got the thought that there *should* be any. You don't need methods to describe relations between objects. Associations are most oftenly implemented with fields, and in case of n-ary relations, with some form of collection in the language you are using (or set, or list, depending on the exact semantics needed).

Comment: Appreciate the help. I suppose i just don't understand how to differentiate a unidirectional vs bidirectional association. This question is just so vague that it's hard to make that distinction, and its just seems safe to assume a bidirectional association. This source http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~cs3443/uml/uml.html shows that you need the fields to tell them apart

Comment: The source tells you that a unidirectional association in UML has a pointy end on one side and a bidirectional association doesn't have a pointy arrow, but is only a line. You really don't need anything more *in an UML diagram* to tell them apart. Of course, in your implementation, stuff is stored in fields. In bidirectional associations, you have a field *on both sides*. In Unidirectional associations, only the "owning" side has a field containing the "owned" object, but not vice-versa.

Comment: That clarifies so much thank you. The question was too ambiguous to tell unidirectional/bidirectional apart. 

Id understand with something like a factory has many machines. Each machine is part of one factory. Then there should be an composition arrowhead pointed to the factory

Comment: You're right that the question is underspecified; the unidirectionality is an expression of what's called "navigability" - e.g., in diagram A, it means that the Team object can access (navigate to) Player objects, but not vice versa (e.g. it holds an array of them). You'll come across this type of design choice often enough, but the question itself doesn't exclude diagram B. In B, the relationship can be interpreted in one of two ways: (1) navigability is left unspecified (e.g., maybe it's an early conceptual model, and it will be worked out at a later point), or (2) it's bidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

The answer key is wrong if the diagram is supposed to match exactly the narrative.

The narrative only provides information about two classes, `Team` and `Player`, an association between the two, and the multiplicities at the association ends, i.e.  `1` and  `1..*`. The diagram B corresponds exactly to that narrative.

The diagram A adds some **[navigability](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability)** that cannot be inferred from the narrative.  It says that at runtime a team instance can easily find the associated player instances. It is not necessarily unidirectional: the other end has an *unspecified* navigability. Absence of navigability from the other end (i.e truly unidirectional) would be shown explicitly with a cross.

The navigability arrow should not be confused with inheritance. To avoid such confusion, the UML specifications mandate an open arrow for navigation, and a large hollow triangle as arrow head for inheritance. (Your diagram uses a small plain arrow head. It’s too small for inheritance, but small open could have prevented any confusion).